# Electrical circuitry

Tags: circuit-analysis

In a neon tester, how does the body complete the circuit even when it's insulated from the ground by footwear and the bulb glows?
I mean is current flowing to the neon bulb?

Comment: Capacitive connections.

Comment: Please change your question's title to be more specific. Nearly every question on this site is about "electrical circuitry"!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please search the site for existing and answered questions like yours before just posting a new one. It's very, very easy.

Comment: Do you know the equivalent circuit of the tester or the hand and the body or how a capacitor works?  The body is a massive dielectric with distributed resistance internally and on the surface (skin) with salty ions. Yet it only needs a tiny part in series from the hand to couple it to the common ground path through the floor and your feet which have high resistance yet a certain capacitance of water dielectric (Dk=80) due to the surface area of your hand and feet and the small gap.